# Find and replace value of an environment variable in source file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables

I have a file which has environment variable listed like

```
 VAR_NAME=abc
```

and this file is sourced when needed. I want to add a new environment variable to the file if it's not present already. How do I search this file and replace/add a new value to it?

I was doing this till now:

```
echo "string_created" >> fileName
```

this just appends a line and after few runs there were multiple lines with diff values. I can remove this file after one run of my program but that isn't definitive.

Comment: If there's already a value set, do you want to remove it and replace it with the new value?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep`:

```
grep -q '^VAR_NAME=' file || echo 'VAR_NAME=abc' >> file
```

`echo` will execute when `grep` returns non-success return code.

Comment: There is a race condition if multiple instances of this script could be running simultaneously. This is hard to fix with just shell script.

Comment: Oh of course most of the shell scripts are not written with that requirement in place. However if there is any chance like that then creating a temporary `.pid` file might help.

Comment: Fixing race conditions in scripts is trivial with `flock`.